# Entity Listener callbacks on subclassed entity not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitylisteners

My project has

- "domain" sub project which includes all the entities
- "services" sub project which contains all the services which includes,JPADao,services etc.Domain project is added to the services project.

Now I have written an EntityListener in services  like below:

```
public class TestEntityListener {
@PrePersist
public void prePersist(Resource r) {
    perform("INSERTED");
}
@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate(Resource r) {
    perform("UPDATED");
}
@PreRemove
public void preRemove(Resource r) {
    perform("DELETED");
}
@Transactional
private void perform(String target) {
    CallLogBaseDaoJpa callLogBaseDaoJpa = BeanUtil.getBean(CallLogBaseDaoJpa.class);
    //callLogBaseDaoJpa.persist(target));
}
```

}

Bean Util is below:

```
@Service
public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

Now I have to annotate entity class (Resource) with @TestListener but I am not able to as my entities are in domain project and do not have access to services.

To mitigate this,I tried subclassing Resource as below and added entityListener to this subclass.I can keep this Resource1 in services and all such references will resolved for me But in this scenario my test listeners arent getting invoked

```
  @Entity
  @EntityListeners({TestEntityListener.class})
  public class Resource1 extends Resource    
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6723893476944789741L;
    }
```

1)Is my expectation of listeners getting invoked by subclassing the original entity method

misplaced ?Is it not expected to work ?

2)Am I doing it right or if someone can please suggest any other approach without  changing my dependencies will be welcome?

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work  a `Resource` isn't a `Resource1` so changes to that class don't apply to the super class.

Comment: Is there anyother alternative to achieving the intended effect as I seem to not able to use entity listeners in the correct format due to the project dependencies

Comment: add an `orm.xml` and specify the listener on the `Resource` class via that file